# opencv imshow not reading image windows 10

Tags: python-2.7, opencv3.0

I am trying to read an image using opecv and imshow, but I am getting this error:

```
cv2.error: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win32-vc12-static\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:281: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

Here is my code:

```
from colors import colorsDescriptors
from tafuta import tafutA
import argparse
import cv2
import sys

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--index", required = True,
            help="path to place where features are to be stored")
ap.add_argument("-q", "--query", required =True,
            help="path to the images that are to be queried")
# ap.add_argument("-r", "--result-path", required = True,
#                 help="path to the image result")
ap.add_argument("-r", "--result", required = True,
            help="path to the image result")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

description = colorsDescriptors((8, 12, 3))
query = cv2.imread(args["query"])
features = description.explain(query)
search = tafutA(args["index"])
results = search.search(features)

cv2.imshow("Inline", query)

for (score, resultsId) in results:
    result = cv2.imread(args["result"]+ "/" + resultsId )

cv2.imshow("matokeo", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: 99% of the time, this error is because imread() didn't read anything in the first place (you gave it the wrong path). Check if query==None